# Data transformation involving dictionaries and lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

My initial problem is to transform a `List` of `Mapping`s whose values are `List`s of values. The transformed list must contain the Cartesian product of all lists (those that are values in the dictionaries) that belong to separate dictionaries (in other words, the values of the lists present in the same directories are "coupled").

Basically, if you disregard the keys of the dictionaries, this would be solved simply with `itertools.product`.

**Input:**

```
[
   {
      ('B3G', 'B1'): [1.0, 2.0], 
      ('B1G', 'B1'): [11.0, 12.0]
   }, 
   {
      ('B2G', 'B1'): [1.5, 2.5, 3.5]
   }
]
```

**Output:**

```
[
  {('B3G', 'B1'): 1.0, ('B1G', 'B1'): 11.0, ('B2G', 'B1'): 1.5},
  {('B3G', 'B1'): 1.0, ('B1G', 'B1'): 11.0, ('B2G', 'B1'): 2.5},
  {('B3G', 'B1'): 1.0, ('B1G', 'B1'): 11.0, ('B2G', 'B1'): 3.5},
  {('B3G', 'B1'): 2.0, ('B1G', 'B1'): 12.0, ('B2G', 'B1'): 1.5},
  {('B3G', 'B1'): 2.0, ('B1G', 'B1'): 12.0, ('B2G', 'B1'): 2.5},
  {('B3G', 'B1'): 2.0, ('B1G', 'B1'): 12.0, ('B2G', 'B1'): 3.5}
]
```

To make the matter more confusing, the keys of each dictionaries are `Tuple`s of strings.

Here is a possible implementation, using a `class` to isolate the whole mess.

```
@dataclass
class ParametricMapping:
"""Abstraction for multi-dimensional parametric mappings."""

mappings: List[Mapping[Tuple[str], Sequence[float]]] = field(default_factory=lambda: [{}])

@property
def combinations(self) -> List[Mapping[Tuple[str], float]]:
    """Cartesian product adapted to work with dictionaries, roughly similar to `itertools.product`."""

    labels = [label for arg in self.mappings for label in tuple(arg.keys())]
    pools = [list(map(tuple, zip(*arg.values()))) for arg in self.mappings]

    def cartesian_product(*args):
        """Cartesian product similar to `itertools.product`"""
        result = [[]]
        for pool in args:
            result = [x + [y] for x in result for y in pool]
        return result

    results = []
    for term in cartesian_product(*pools):
        results.append([pp for p in term for pp in p])

    tmp = []
    for r in results:
        tmp.append({k: v for k, v in zip(labels, r)})

    if len(tmp) == 0:
        return [{}]
    else:
        return tmp
```

**Question**: How can I improve this to make it cleaner (priority #1) and faster (#2)?

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR:** Scroll to the end for the provided code with suggested improvements

## Suggestions

#### 1. Standalone `cartesian_product` helper function outside scope of `combinations`

A preferable solution would be to simply use `itertools.product` as most Python-savvy readers will be familiar with it - and it is well-documented for those that aren’t. However, since you explicitly mention it...

*If you still don't want to use `itertools.product`:*

While it does improve clarity to construct a hierarchy of scopes that expose things only when necessary, in this case, I believe that making `cartesian_product` a nested function inside `combinations` serves only to confuse the purpose of `combinations`. It is better to define `cartesian_product` above, making the code below cleaner and easier to understand. Now someone reading your code will first see `cartesian_product`’s definition and understand its relatively simple purpose. Then, inside `ParametricMapping.combinations`, readers are already familiar with `cartesian_product`, and their train of thought isn’t derailed by trying to understand a nested function.

#### 2. `flatten` helper function

This helper function should be used thusly:

```py
for term in cartesian_product(*pools):
    results.append(flatten(term))
```

This may seem silly as flattening is a simple operation, but in this example there are a few fairly tricky list/dict comprehensions nearby. Therefore, it may help to replace that piece with a simple `flatten` call to clean up some confusion and to emphasize that this is  a straight-forward operation - A fact that could be lost on some readers of the code in its current state. My point here is that stacking lots of loops and comprehensions on top of each other (especially without documentation/comments) can quickly get messy and confusing.

#### 3. Consolidate some code

If you took both of the above suggestions, a nice opportunity to consolidate some code has presented itself. After the above changes, the section that was originally

```py
results = []
for term in cartesian_product(*pools):
    results.append([pp for p in term for pp in p])
```

should now be

```py
results = []
for term in itertools.product(*pools):
    results.append(flatten(term))
```

This block can be expressed clearly and concisely with the following list comprehension:

```py
results = [flatten(term) for term in itertools.product(*pools)]
```

Note that because of the separation of functionality into helper functions, the purpose of this list comprehension is abundantly clear. It creates `results`, which is a list containing the `flatten`ed outputs of `product`.

#### 4. Check for empty `mappings` at top of `combinations`

Instead of the if/else at the end of `combinations` that checks for `len(tmp) == 0`, make the first two lines of `combinations` the following:

```py
if self.mappings == [{}]:
    return [{}]
```

The `else` clause at the bottom of `combinations` is no longer necessary, and you can simply `return tmp`. This is cleaner because it handles the case where `mappings` is empty immediately, which means those cases bypass all the code that was being executed before when `len(tmp)` was evaluated at the end of `combinations`. This also allows readers to make the assumption that `mappings` is non-empty when they get into the actual work being done by `combinations`, which is just one less thing to worry about. Alternatively, a more concise option would be to replace

```py
if len(tmp) == 0:
    return [{}]
else:
    return tmp
```

with

```py
return tmp or [{}]
```

This works because if `mappings` is empty, the value of `tmp` will be an empty list, which will evaluate to False, returning the value following the `or`. This more concise version may come at the cost of decreased readability.

#### 5. Define `labels` and `pools` using helper methods or non-init fields

Remove the first two code lines from `combinations`, and move them to either helper methods, or [additional fields that are processed post-initialization](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#post-init-processing). I recommend doing this to further clarify the work actually being done by `combinations` and to clean up the code overall. These both have the added benefit of exposing `labels` and `pools` as additional attributes of the `dataclass` that can be accessed outside of `combinations`.

See the `ParametricMapping1` class defined in the section below for an implementation using helper methods, and see the alternative `ParametricMapping2` class defined below it for an implementation using non-init fields.

## TL;DR

In the end, if all suggestions are followed, the code should include the below declaration of `flatten`, along with one of the two following blocks (`ParametricMapping1`, **or** `ParametricMapping2`):

```py
def flatten(l):
    return [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

**With either ...**

```py
@dataclass
class ParametricMapping1:
    mappings: List[Mapping[Tuple[str], Sequence[float]]] = field(default_factory=lambda: [{}])

    def _labels(self) -> List[Tuple[str]]:
        return flatten(self.mappings)

    def _pools(self) -> List[List[Sequence[float]]]:
        return [list(map(tuple, zip(*arg.values()))) for arg in self.mappings]

    @property
    def combinations(self) -> List[Mapping[Tuple[str], float]]:
        if self.mappings == [{}]:
            return [{}]

        pool_values = [flatten(term) for term in itertools.product(*self._pools())]
        return [dict(zip(self._labels(), v)) for v in pool_values]
```

**Or ...**

```py
@dataclass
class ParametricMapping2:
    mappings: List[Mapping[Tuple[str], Sequence[float]]] = field(default_factory=lambda: [{}])
    labels: List[Tuple[str]] = field(init=False, repr=False)
    pools: List[List[Sequence[float]]] = field(init=False, repr=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.labels = flatten(self.mappings)
        self.pools = [list(map(tuple, zip(*arg.values()))) for arg in self.mappings]

    @property
    def combinations(self) -> List[Mapping[Tuple[str], float]]:
        pool_values = [flatten(term) for term in itertools.product(*self.pools)]
        return [dict(zip(self.labels, v)) for v in pool_values] or [{}]
```

**Edit (2019-01-09 - 1530):**

- The definitions of `_labels` and `self.labels` in the above two code blocks, respectively, have been simplified per @MathiasEttinger's [excellent suggestion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/211121/data-transformation-involving-dictionaries-and-lists/211155#comment408288_211155). See revision history for their original definitions.

Comment: Nice answer. Two thoughts though: isn't `labels` simply `flatten(mappings)`? And isn't `zip` already returning `tuple`s? Why keep the `map` call?

Comment: Also I like to define `flatten` in terms of `itertools.chain.from_iterable`. But it's mostly a matter of personal taste.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I will investigate in details. @MathiasEttinger I didn't get your second point.

Comment: @CedricH. I usually define `flatten = itertools.chain.from_iterable` as I prefer to work with iterables, but as an alternative to the `flatten` proposed by this answer, you could have `def flatten(iterable): return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(iterable))` instead. As said, there might not be much of a difference appart for style.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Got it. I also changed the definition of `labels` based on your first comment.

Comment: Hunter, Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. I edited the question to show the final implementation I chose based on your answer and on the comments above.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger, thank you! You’re absolutely right! I missed that. Defining `labels` as `flatten(self.mappings)` is certainly better! I’ll edit my answer to mention your improvement.

Comment: @Mathias Ettinger, `itertools.chain.from_iterable` is also a great alternative I had forgotten about. Thanks for bringing that up! @Cedric H., I’m glad you found the suggestions helpful!